# SharePoint Online - PowerShell edit items in Quick Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Is it possible to edit the items in an existing Quick Links web part using PowerShell PnP? I have seen posts about using the SharePoint workbench to get the JSON required to create a new web part. However, I want to add or remove items from an existing web part.

I tried using Get-PnPClientSideComponent to get the PropertiesJSON but this doesn't appear to include the full JSON that the workbench produces. So there isn't an items collection to work with (although I admit I might be missing something).

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started down the road of building a function that returns the complete json from the component received from `Get-PnPClientSideComponent`.

The information is all there. It certainly can be improved upon but hope it helps:

```
function Get-PnpQuickLinksJson{

    param(
      [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.CanvasControl]$component
    )

    $json = "{
        'controlType': $($component.SpControlData.ControlType),
        'id': '$($component.SpControlData.Id)',
        'position': {
            'zoneIndex': $($component.SpControlData.Position.ZoneIndex),
            'sectionIndex': $($component.SpControlData.Position.SectionIndex),
            'controlIndex': $($component.SpControlData.Position.ControlIndex),
            'layoutIndex': $($component.SpControlData.Position.LayoutIndex)
        },
        'webPartId': '$($component.SpControlData.WebPartId)',

        'webPartData': {
            'id': '$($component.SpControlData.WebPartId)',
            'instanceId': '$($component.SpControlData.Id)',
            'title': 'Quick links',
            'description': '$($component.Description)',
            'serverProcessedContent': $($component.serverProcessedContent.ToString()),
            'dataVersion': '2.2',
            'properties': $($component.PropertiesJson)
        },
        'emphasis': {},
        'reservedHeight': 146,
        'reservedWidth': 744,
        'addedFromPersistedData': true
    }";
    #clean up characters for consistency
    $json = $json.Replace("'",'"').Replace("`n", "").Replace("`t", "").Replace("`r", "");
    $jsonObj = ConvertTo-Json $json;
    return $jsonObj | ConvertFrom-Json;
}
```