# SharePoint Online - How to edit/delete QuickLinks webpart item using PnP Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, quick-links

How to **delete/update** link highlighted below in **Quick Links webpart** in **SharePoint Online** using PnP Powershell?

This reference not giving how to pass component? to extract webpart details. [SharePoint Online - PowerShell edit items in Quick Links](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272531/sharepoint-online-powershell-edit-items-in-quick-links). **PropertiesJson** is not returning any existing links.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quick Links is quite tricky. I've tried to parse the link value and reset back but it's a bit tedious, since the format from `properties` to get the existing link and compared to `PropertiesJson` when you set back, is totally drastic.

Note: ID is a running number. I forgot what's itemType for, but it seems the link type when you select Change the link on the web part, which is 2 is a direct link.
If itemType is 3, you need to specify the SharePoint List/Document Library ID instead.

I found this format the hard way since it's undocumented anywhere.

```
"PropertiesJson": {
        "title": "Quick Access",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Shared Documents",
                "sourceItem": {
                    "url": "https://meme.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents",
                    "itemType": 2,
                    "fileExtension": "",
                    "progId": ""
                },
                "id": 1,
                "thumbnailType": 2,
                "fabricReactIcon": {
                    "iconName": "doclibrary"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Policy & Procedures",
                "sourceItem": {
                    "url": "https://meme.sharepoint.com/PolicyProcedures",
                    "itemType": 2,
                    "fileExtension": "",
                    "progId": ""
                },
                "id": 2,
                "thumbnailType": 2,
                "fabricReactIcon": {
                    "iconName": "doclibrary"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Templates",
                "sourceItem": {
                    "url": "https://meme.sharepoint.com/Templates",
                    "itemType": 2,
                    "fileExtension": "",
                    "progId": ""
                },
                "id": 3,
                "thumbnailType": 2,
                "fabricReactIcon": {
                    "iconName": "doclibrary"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Private Documents",
                "sourceItem": {
                    "url": "https://meme.sharepoint.com/PrivateDocs",
                    "itemType": 2,
                    "fileExtension": "",
                    "progId": ""
                },
                "id": 4,
                "thumbnailType": 2,
                "fabricReactIcon": {
                    "iconName": "pagelock"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Department Forms",
                "sourceItem": {
                    "url": "https://meme.sharepoint.com/DeptForms",
                    "itemType": 2,
                    "fileExtension": "",
                    "progId": ""
                },
                "id": 5,
                "thumbnailType": 2,
                "fabricReactIcon": {
                    "iconName": "formlibrary"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: How did you parse QLWP? as PnP powershell is not returning any existing links for me PropertiesJson

$webpart = $page.Controls | ? {$_.Title -eq "Quick links"}
$webpartJson = $webpart.PropertiesJson